# OCR-Extract only the words I want

Tags: python, ocr, invoice

[Example of an Invoice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cs2T.jpg)

Hello dear Community,

so i have figured out how to extract all the words and numbers from an invoice using EasyOCR in Python. But now I want to extract only certain words like in the photo. Keep in mind that I want to have it working for different types of invoices.

One idea: To extract all the words that lie right below the word "product description" or "Total/Total Price". I have yet to figure how to implement that in a code. How could I do it ?

Or do you have other ideas how to do that?

Very happy for your inspirations.

Answer (score 1):

Since most office multifunctional printer/scanners these days can do passable OCR (this is saved as a separate layer in the PDF), it is relatively straightforward to extract text from a PDF, even a scanned invoice.
There are several PDF libraries that allow you to extract text. Or you can use `subprocess` to call `pdftotext` from the poppler-utils package.

But given the wide variety in formatting of invoices, deciphering which text is what is almost inpossible to automate. Here the Mk I eyeball & brain are still unbeaten, AFAIK.

Besides, it is common to do three way matching between an order you sent, the goods received from the supplier and the invoice from the supplier. So that means the invoice will have to contain at least your order number, and you have to extract that as well.

In the administration systems I'm familiar with, decoding invoices and three-way matching is still a job for a human.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes the order number or the Full name would also be something of interest. The two variables I desscribed were just to give an example.

Comment: Having thought about how we do it at $WORK, it is not the OCR that is a problem anymore. See updates answer.

Answer (score -1):

I do believe however, this could be possible with a bunch of IF conditions and then IF conditions nested within the prior conditions. But I will post an update once I have time to keep working on this.

Comment: Don't submit answer like "surly try when i have time", If you have time then please do solve, or else you can solve when you have time and post full answer.